# How to get data from a searchResult object python

Tags: python

I'm quite new to python and trying to use this module for a project (https://pypi.org/project/rttapi/). It returns a searchResult object which I am unsure how to access as it says it is not subscriptable.

I am running the example lines given:

```
from rttapi.api import RttApi
api = RttApi('rttapi_exampleuser', '00112233aabbccdd')
departures = api.search_station_departures('EDB')
print(departures)
```

It returns this:

`<rttapi.model.SearchResult object at 0x0000020845E5BEE0>`

How do I get the information out of this? If I try accessing it like an array it says it is not subscriptable and I haven't found anything online to help.

Any help much appreciated!

Comment: Try `print(dir(departures))` to see what all are the properties and method it has.

Comment: @AbdulNiyasPM it gives me this: `['__class__', '__delattr__', '__dict__', '__dir__', '__doc__', '__eq__', '__format__', '__ge__', '__getattribute__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__init_subclass__', '__le__', '__lt__', '__module__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', '__weakref__', 'filter', 'location', 'services']`